# Send a class from another class for Inheritance

Tags: c#, inheritance, types

Is there any way to send a class from another class to use for inherit ?

Why cant I do this :

```
    public class myClass{
    Type mClass; 

    class c : mClass
    {

    }
}
```

I want to get a class from MyClass Constructor (Using Type ) then create class "c" with inherit of "mClass".

Is it possible in c# ? Am I right to send a class like variable (Type) ?!

thank u for read

Comment: what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: Yes. Maybe telling what you want to do will help answering the question.

Comment: @Alireza Sadast mikham ye class ro baraye ye class dg baraye ers bari befrestam . Ye soal adam miporse 200 nafre mizanan roo saresh

Comment: You have chosen the right answer anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot inherit from another class by `Type` object; this simply doesn't make sense.  Classes are emitted at compile time, and variables exist at runtime.

You would have to use the `System.Reflection.Emit` mechanism to create the class definition dynamically at runtime.